# Prove that a sequence of functions converges in measure

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Show that $f_n(x)=e^{-n|1-\sin x|}$ converges in measure to $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$.

For this, we need to prove that, given $\varepsilon>0,$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\{x\in[a,b]: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\}\right)=0.$$

$$|f_n(x)-0|=e^{-n|1-\sin (x)|}<\varepsilon\Rightarrow |1-\sin (x)|<\frac1n\log\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right)$$

So, it is enough to prove that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu\{x\in[a,b]: |1-\sin (x)|<\frac{1}{n}\log(1/\epsilon)\}=0.$$

We can neglect that $\log\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right)$ term, otherwise, see that there exists $M\in\Bbb N$ such that $\log\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right)<M$.

So, it is enough to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\left\{x\in[a,b]: |1-\sin (x)|<\frac{M}n\right\}\right)=0.$$

Equivalently,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\left\{x\in[a,b]:x\in\left(\sin^{-1}\left(1-\frac{M}n\right),\sin^{-1}\left(1+\frac{M}n\right)\right)\right\}\right)=0.$$

As $n\to\infty$, $M/n\to 0$. Then, $x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi$.

As $[a,b]$ is a finite interval, there are finitely many $k$ such that $\frac\pi2+2k\pi$ is in $[a,b]$

Suppose $x_{k_i}=\frac\pi2+2k_i\pi$ for $i=1,\cdots,l$ are the only such elements in $[a,b]$.

We then have $$\left\{x\in[a,b]:x\in\left(\sin^{-1}\left(1-\frac{M}n\right),\sin^{-1}\left(1+\frac{M}n\right)\right)\right\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^l B\left(x_{k_i},g(n)\right)$$

$g(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

So, $$\begin{aligned}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left(\left\{x\in[a,b]:x\in\left(\sin^{-1}\left(1-\frac{M}n\right),\sin^{-1}\left(1+\frac{M}n\right)\right)\right\}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^l B(x_{k_i},g(n)\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^l\mu\left(B\left(x_{k_i},g(n)\right)\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^l g(n)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^l\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=0.\end{aligned}$$

I realize that the condition $[a,b]$ is necessary, otherwise, we can have $g(n)=\frac1n$ and infinitely many $x_i$'s and we then have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\ne 0$.

Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Your attempt looks correct.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : Thanks

Comment: I think there is a typo, there should be $>$ instead $$|f_n(x)-0|=e^{-n|1-\sin (x)|}<\varepsilon\Rightarrow |1-\sin (x)|\color{red}>\frac1n\log\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right),$$ but, from there, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$A_n:=\left\{x\in[a,b]: \left|1-\sin (x)\right|<\frac{M}{n}\right\}.$$
Then the sequence $(A_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing and the intersection of $A_n$'s has measure $0$. Since $A_1$ has a finite measure, we conclude that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\lambda(A_n)=0$.

Comment: This is definitely a better way of solving the problem than my way. I have done some thing. Please comment on that. Thanks.